# update the properties of a copy of an instance wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, drag-and-drop, listbox

I have two listboxes. One source listbox which is binded to `ObservableCollection<Person> MyNetwork` The other listbox is my target listbox which is binded to `ObservableCollection<Person> Crew`.Each time I drop the item in the target listbox I create a new instance of the `sourceItem`.

Now I would like to update the properties of new istances, but it doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to make the copies of the sourceItems to update when I change one of the `sourceItems(FirstName)` properties. I'm pretty new to WPF and MVVM and wonder if this is possible or is there a work around to achieve this?

Here what I have so far:
in the `ViewModel`

Source ListBox:

```
private ObservableCollection<Person> _myNetwork = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
public ObservableCollection<Person> MyNetwork
{
    get { return _myNetwork; }
    set { _myNetwork = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
}
```

Target ListBox:

```
private ObservableCollection<Person> _crew = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
public ObservableCollection<Person> Crew
{
    get { return _crew; }
    set { _crew = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Crew");}
}

 void IDropTarget.Drop(IDropInfo dropInfo)
{
    Person sourceItem = dropInfo.Data as Person;

    if (dropInfo.Data is Person)
    {
        Person person = new Person(sourceItem.FirstName,
                                   sourceItem.LastName,
                                   sourceItem.Profession);
        Crew.Add(person);
     }
}
```

The Model:

```
public Person(string FirstName, string LastName, string Profession)
{
       _firstName = FirstName;
       _lastName = LastName;
       _profession = Profession;
}

private string _firstName; 
public string FirstName    
{
    get { return this._firstName; }
    set { this._firstName = value; RaisePropertyChanged("FirstName"); }
}

private string _lastName;
public string LastName  
{
   get { return _lastName; }
   set { _lastName = value; RaisePropertyChanged("LastName"); }
}

private string _profession; 
public string Profession   
{
    get { return _profession; }
    set { _profession = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Profession"); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a library that wraps the **PropertyChanged** event so it's easier to update your properties when you need to call them.

Once example is [Caliburn for WPF](http://caliburnmicro.com/). You can use `NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => FirstName)` from within your code to update the FirstName property however you need to (it doesn't have to just be used in the setter).

Here is a good article on how to use [it](https://claytonone.wordpress.com/2014/06/17/caliburn-micro-part-2-basics-of-databinding/).

Example:

```
using Caliburn.Micro;

namespace CaliburnMicroExample
{
    public class ShellViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
    {
        private string _message;

        public string Message
        {
            get { return _message; }
            set
            {
                _message = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Message);
            }
        }

        public ShellViewModel()
        {
            Message = "Hello World";
        }
    }
}
```